# How to read element.style.top?

Tags: javascript, html, css, casting

It is possible to move an element using :

```
var element = document.getElementById("animate");
element.style.top = 10 + "px"; 
element.style.left = 10 + "px";
```

So why is it not possible to read the position using :

```
var element = document.getElementById("animate");
var vertical = element.style.top; 
var horizontal = element.style.left;
document.getElementById("write0").innerHTML = "vertical = " + vertical + " horizontal = " + horizontal;
```

The answer to that snippet is "vertical = horizontal = "

How are we supposed to read it? I tried adding .toString() but the result was the same.

Comment: Are you sure you've set these in the first place? Sometimes a script can be loaded before others so the value would be null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The javascript code does work.

However, the crucial thing as to whether the `top` and `left` properties actually do anything is the value of the element's `position` property in your CSS.

```js
var element = document.getElementById("animate");
element.style.top = 10 + "px"; 
element.style.left = 10 + "px";

var vertical = element.style.top; 
var horizontal = element.style.left;
document.getElementById("write").innerHTML = "vertical = " + vertical + " horizontal = " + horizontal;



var element = document.getElementById("animate2");
element.style.top = 10 + "px"; 
element.style.left = 10 + "px";

var vertical = element.style.top; 
var horizontal = element.style.left;
document.getElementById("write2").innerHTML = "vertical = " + vertical + " horizontal = " + horizontal;
```

```css
#animate {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: red;
}

#animate2 {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="animate"></div>
<div id="write"></div>

<div id="animate2"></div>
<div id="write2"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer is that you cannot set `top` or `left` on an element with position:static. Setting position:relative lets you use top and left as offsets from static position.

Answer (score 1):

#animate must be having the style:

```
position:relative; | position:absolute; | position:fixed;
```